# Change or override the behavior of a USB keyboard to a more generic controller

Tags: language-agnostic, keyboard, usb, midi, hid

[Changing the keystrokes of a USB keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706543/changing-the-keystrokes-of-a-usb-keyboard)

My question is very similar to the one above... (to which there was no clear answer)

I have a nice USB keyboard that I would like to use to control an audio/visual program I am writing. I **can't** have the USB keyboard input interfere with the regular operating system interface -

Therefore I need to have the OS recognize it as a generic HID device of some kind, or a MIDI device, or something that sends OSC messages.

I am writing the program on OSX but would like to figure out a cross platform solution that doesn't involve me hacking the hardware of the keyboard - hopefully some sort of program or script that I can use. The reason for this is I'd like to distribute this program for others to use easily.

Any ideas on where to start? I'm thinking I'll probably need to write a separate program for users to select a USB device and reroute that into my program...

Any language is fine - I write code in Python, sometimes C, and Java / Processing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're going to find this EXTREMELY difficult to do: most modern operating systems will automatically detect the HID profile and load the drivers for it, and generally speaking make it very difficult to override that default behavior.

Without hacking the hardware you would need to somehow override the OS's default behavior for that specific USB VID (vendor ID) and PID (product ID) and instruct the OS to load your own custom kernel extension? I'd suggest starting with source of the AppleUSBKeyboard drivers at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOUSBFamily/IOUSBFamily-206.4.1/AppleUSBKeyboard/ and then figuring out how to install your custom build as the preferred USB driver for your specific keyboard's VID and PID. After that it should be the messy messy messy issue of only sending the keys to your app and not to anything else.

Comment: Would it be possible to write a function that disables regular operating system keyboard input for all keys except something like ESC if my program is in focus?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to write a
>   function that disables regular
>   operating system keyboard input for
>   all keys except something like ESC if
>   my program is in focus? – jeffrey May
>   24 at 21:59

Yes this should be quite possible, I dont know about Mac but on Win32 you want a global keyboard hook (look up SetWindowsHookEx)